# Not able to connect my service with Redis

Tags: node.js, nginx, redis, backend, pm2

My server is located on client premise.
I'm facing an issue, in that my service(node js) is not able to connect with redis.
If I'm checking the status of redis it's running fine.
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

```
    Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-15 14:16:34 EAT; 18h ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
   Main PID: 3085148 (redis-server)
     Status: "Ready to accept connections"
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 19104)
     Memory: 8.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
```

I'm able to connect with the service manually from one server providing host and port.
But the issue is when my service is trying to connect so it's failing.

So can anyone help me in suggesting what could be a possible reason for the same?

**Error:**

```
    [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
16|pdsl_pa |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/stage_env/pdsl_parking_service/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/index.js:318:37)
16|pdsl_pa |     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:645:28)
16|pdsl_pa |     at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
16|pdsl_pa |     at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
16|pdsl_pa |     at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:501:8)
16|pdsl_pa |     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
16|pdsl_pa |     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
16|pdsl_pa | [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.**.***.***:6379
16|pdsl_pa |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)
16|pdsl_pa | [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.**.***.***:6379
16|pdsl_pa |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)
16|pdsl_pa | [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.**.***.***:6379
```